# java sql SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I keep getting this error when trying to connect to the database.

This is my prepared statement

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM `?` WHERE `HomeTeam` = '?'";
        PreparedStatement prepst;            

        prepst =  con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        prepst.setString(1,box1.getSelectedItem().toString());
        prepst.setString(2,box1.getSelectedItem().toString());
        rs = prepst.executeQuery();
```

Anyone know why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is in `'` and ``` symbols. You should fix the sql as follwing:

`String SQL = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE HomeTeam = ?";`

However I am not sure that parameter placeholder `?` is supported after `from`. So, propbably you will have to put it yourself, e.g.:

```
String table = box1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE HomeTeam = ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE HomeTeam = ?";
```

Don't use ` to nest parameters, use ' to nest values you're comparing against if you're hard coding them.

You can't use ? to specify a table name.

Comment: Ok,I've tried that and now I get a MySQL syntax error although the SQL statement works when I tried it manually on the database

Comment: You can't use ? to specify a table name